# Path aliases not updating or setting automatically

Tags: path-aliases, distributions

I have an Open Atrium site where the path aliases are not generated automatically and not updated if I change them manually.

How can I fix this?

Comment: do aliases already exist for the content (regardless of whether or not they are the correct aliases) and what happens if you try a Bulk Update?

Answer (score 0):

The aliases are generated when you create an object in your site and are based upon the pathauto patterns (placeholders) you specify at:

For 6.x: `Administer > Site Building > URL aliases`, in the "Automated alias settings" tab.

For 7.x: `Administer > Configuration > Search and Metadata > URL aliases`, in the "Patterns" tab.

Pattern tab provides several default patterns that automatically alias the different content types.

Settings tab allows to refine length and case, as well as defining if an alias is to be replaced or added to the list.

Comment: All of those are configured. However, they do not update on save